# An algebra on a finite set is a $\sigma$-algebra on the finite set.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am learning probability theory, and it is my desire to prove the following statement: an algebra on a finite set is a $\sigma$-algebra on the finite set.

Let $\Omega$ be finite and $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra on $\Omega$. By definition, we have the following facts: $\mathcal{A} \subseteq 2^{\Omega}$ (power set); $\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$; $\mathcal{A}$ is $\setminus$-closed; $\mathcal{A}$ is $\cup$-closed.

To prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, we only need to prove $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under countable unions. This requires me to go from finite unions to infinite unions.

Let $S$ be a sequence on $\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $S_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$. Then it is my desire to prove that $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} S_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$. How to prove it using the given facts?

Comment: What is wrong with saying $\mathcal A$ is finite (it is a subset of $2^{\Omega}$) so any countable union of elements of $\mathcal A$  is a finite union  of elements of $\mathcal A$ when you remove duplicates.

Comment: Well, if $\Omega$ is finite, can you actually have infinitely many distinct sets in your countable collection?

Comment: @Henry Ha, seems to be the case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have finitely many sets to work with, any uncountable union must be actually a finite union: Since the Number of elements in the truncated union $\bigcup_{i=0}^n A_i$ is non decreasing in function of $n$, there must be finitely many indicies $n_1,…n_k$ where the number of elements strictly increased. Otherwise the countable union would be an infinite set. Now we see, that $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A_i=A_{n_1} \cup …\cup A_{n_k}$, since these sets are the only sets contributing to new elements in the unions. Therefore we represented the infinite union as a finite one.